# Error 404 after $http.post Ionic - Android build

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

We are developing a mobile app using the Ionic framework. Here are the config.xml and index.html files:

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.manageyourmatch988887" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>manageyourmatch</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
      Ionic Framework Team
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
```

index.html

```
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

When we perform a post request in the loginCtrl.js on the device we get the 404 error. What are we missing? We allowed all sources through the whitelist using the access tag and the CSP tag.

loginCtrl - http post

```
$http.post(APP_CONFIG.serverUrl, // server url for connetion
            {action : "login", cell_num : $scope.model.telephone, password : $scope.model.password} // data passed by json post
            ).then(
            function(response) { // if i recive a response from the server
                console.log(response.data);

                if(response.data.status == "success"){ // if the server accepts my login
                    // show toast [native] or an alertPopup [all platforms]
                    if(typeof window.plugins !== "undefined")
                        window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom('Response: ' + response.data.status);
                    else
                        $ionicPopup.alert({title: 'Server response', template: ''+response.data.status});

                    // test the vibration [HTML5 all platforms]
                    //navigator.vibrate(1000);

                    // Update localStorage
                    localStorage.setItem("telephone", $scope.model.telephone);
                    localStorage.setItem("loggedin", "true");
                    localStorage.setItem("session_id", response.data.session_id);

                    // Go to homepage
                    $state.go('home.matches');
                }else{
                    // if the login fail due to bad username and password (or something else...)
                    $ionicPopup.alert({
                            title: 'Error message',
                            template: ''+response.data.error_message
                        });
                }
            }, function(error) { // if something goes wrong
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Connection failed',
                        template: 'Error: '+JSON.stringify(error)
                    });
            });
```

Comment: Post more code please, i love code! (Hint, show only relevant parts)

Comment: I edited, thank you @Arg0n

Comment: Are you sure that your `APP_CONFIG.serverUrl` contains correct url ?

Comment: Hi @Ashot, yes I checked and the url is correct

Comment: Does your api work correctly ?

Comment: Yes, we tried the app also using the browser and there worked correctly

Comment: Did you set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in your backend? I think there is no problem with your client code.

Comment: Where is your `whitelist` plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; &apos;unsafe-eval&apos; *; style-src  &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; &apos;unsafe-eval&apos; *">
```